# How to add id to an underscore template using Jade

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, pug

I have this underscore template that I want to add ids to but for some reason I am not getting the result that I want

```
 script(type="text/template" id="facts")                                                  
              div.fact.col-md-12(id="fact<%= count %>")
                    div.col-md-8
                      div.col-md-2
                        | Fact  <%= count %>
                      div.col-md-10
```

gives me

```
<div id="facts-container" class="col-md-12">
<div id="fact&lt;%= count %&gt;" class="fact col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      Fact 1
    </div>
```

I want to be able to add an id with a count attached to the id, how should I go about this ?

Comment: did you try `id="fact{{<%= count %>}}"`

Comment: yes, i did but it doesn't render the template at all once i use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `!=` to avoid escaping the output text.

http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/ (Unescaped Buffered Code)

**Jade**

```
div.fact.col-md-12(id!="fact#<%= count %>")
  div.col-md-8
    div.col-md-2
      | Fact  <%= count %>
    div.col-md-10
```

**Output HTML**

```
<div id="fact#<%= count %>" class="fact col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="col-md-2">Fact  <%= count %></div>
    <div class="col-md-10"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, adding != fixed the problem